# migrations within transactions

Tags: mysql, migration, transaction

I have a bash script to run migrations on our MySQL databases.

Is it possible to wrap migrations within a single transaction when running multiple migration scripts from the command line?

Occasionally we've had schema changes that require some data manipulation to migrate that into the new structure and maintain referential integrity.

I'd love to do something like: (assume all vars are set accordingly)

```
mysql `mysql -h$DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME -e "START TRANSACTION;"`
for i in $( ls $MIGRATIONS_FOLDER/migration-* ); do

    # check database for record of this file
    result=`mysql -h$DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME -e 
            "SELECT id,filename,ran FROM tbl_migrations WHERE filename='$i'" 
            --batch --raw | wc -l`

    # if there is a record in tbl_migrations for this file, skip it
    if (($result > 1)); then
        continue
    fi;

    echo "Importing $i";

    result=`mysql -h$DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME < $i`

    if [[summatz screwed up]]
    then
        mysql `mysql -h$DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME -e "ROLLBACK;"`
        exit
    fi


    mysql -h$DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME -e 
            "INSERT INTO tbl_migrations (filename, ran) VALUES ('$i', 1)"

    if [ "$i" = "$END" ]; then
        echo "Ending migration at user specified file $i"
        break
    fi

done
mysql `mysql -h$DB_HOST -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME -e "COMMIT;"`
```

Comment: Schema changes can't be rolled back, they're not "transactional". Most (all?) DDL will implicitly commit before it runs.

Comment: thanks @Mat - I think I'll look at an alternative. tyvm!

Comment: Use PostgreSQL if you're looking for transactional DDL, works as it should.